# Need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: r, plot, charts, trading

I am attempting to code a trading strategy in R, and I wish to plot the equity curve. Here's the code:

### Get the data

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("MMM")
```

### Calculate the DVI indicator

```
MMM_dvi = DVI(Cl(MMM))
```

### Create trading rule

```
signal = Lag(ifelse(MMM_dvi$dvi < 0.5, 1, -1))
```

### Calculate return

```
return = ROC(Cl(MMM))*signal
equity = exp(cumsum(return))
plot(equity)
Error in plot.window(c(1167782400, 1644796800), c(NaN, NaN)) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're producing the same error that `plot(NA, NA)` will give. What is in the `equity` variable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `signal` vector has many leading `NA`. That means `return` has many leading `NA`, so the result of `cumsum(return)` is a vector of only `NA`.

You need to remove the `NA` or replace them with 0 before calling `cumsum()`.

```
returns <- ROC(Cl(MMM)) * signal
returns <- na.fill(returns, 0)  # replace NA with 0
equity <- exp(cumsum(returns))
plot(equity)
```

[image]